# Cutting stock recursion

Tags: c++, beginner, recursion, programming-challenge

This problem is identical to the one [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59088/stock-pipe-cutting-using-recursion):

> Suppose that you have been assigned the job of buying the plumbing
>   pipes for a construction project. Your foreman gives you a list of the
>   varying lengths of pipe needed, but the distributor sells stock pipe
>   only in one fixed size. You can, however, cut each stock pipe in any
>   way needed. Your job is to figure out the minimum number of  stock
>   pipes required to satisfy the list of requests, thereby saving money
>   and minimizing  waste.
>
> Your job is to write a recursive function
>
> ```
> int cutStock(Vector<int> & requests, int stockLength);
> ```
>
> that takes two arguments—a vector of the lengths needed and the length
>   of stock pipe  that the distributor sells—and returns the minimum
>   number of stock pipes needed to  service all requests in the vector.
>   For example, if the vector contains `[ 4, 3, 4, 1, 7, 8 ]`  and the
>   stock pipe length is 10, you can purchase three stock pipes and divide
>   them as  follows:
>
> Pipe 1: 4, 4, 1
>
> Pipe 2: 3, 7
>
> Pipe 3: 8
>
> Doing so leaves you with two small remnants left over. There are other
>   possible  arrangements that also fit into three stock pipes, but it
>   cannot be done with fewer.

```
/*
 * File: StockCutting.cpp
 * ----------------------
 * Name: abdulrhman eaita
 * This code minimize the needed stock for a diffrent length requests
 *
 */

#include <iostream>
#include "console.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "simpio.h"
using namespace std;

/* Function prototypes */

int cutStock(Vector<int> & requests, int stockLength);
void bibesCutter(Vector<int> & requests, int stockLength, int &rest, int &bibes);
/* Main program */

int main() {
   Vector<int> requests;
   while (true) {
       while (true) {
           int x = getInteger("enter your requests, 0 to end: ");
           if(x == 0) break;
           requests.add(x);
       }
       int stoclLen = getInteger("Stock length?: ");
       cout << "Minimum number of stock pipes: " << cutStock(requests, stoclLen) << endl;
       requests.clear();
   }
   return 0;
}

/*
 * Function: cutStock
 * Usage: int units = cutStock(requests, stockLength);
 * ---------------------------------------------------
 * wrapper function for bibesCutter();
 */

int cutStock(Vector<int> & requests, int stockLength) {
    int bibes = 0;
    int rest = 0;
    bibesCutter(requests,stockLength, rest, bibes);
    return bibes;
}
/*
 * Function: bibesCutter
 * USage: bibesCutter(requests, stocklen, rest, bibes);
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 * Computes the minimum number of stock pipes required to satisfy
 * the vector of requests of individual pieces.
 */
void bibesCutter(Vector<int> & requests, int stockLength, int & rest, int & bibes){
    if (requests.size() == 1) {
        if (requests[0] > rest) {
            bibes++;

            //creating new rest as it's new stock and substracting the request after adding new bibe
            rest = stockLength - requests[0];

            return;
        }else{
            // substracting the request from current rest only.
            rest -= requests[0];
            return;
        }
    }else{
        Vector<int> tmp ;
        int toCheck = 0;
        // checking if there's a smaller value to remove first
        for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); ++i) {
            if (requests[i] < rest) {
                toCheck = i;
            }
        }
        // removing first item by default, if there's no smaller cut. 
        tmp += requests[toCheck];
        requests.remove(toCheck);
        bibesCutter(tmp, stockLength, rest, bibes);
        bibesCutter(requests, stockLength, rest, bibes);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, and what is your question?

Comment: @EmilyL. Just review the code in general, if there is no specific question.

Comment: What is a `Vector`? Is that your own special class or do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: @jliv902 yes it's a special class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **`void` function**

  The `bibesCutter` itself doesn't care how many bibes have been claimed already. It only calculates how many are needed for the remaining requests. Therefore I'd recommend to change its signature to

  ```
  int bibesCutter(Vector<int> & requests, int stockLength, int & rest)
  ```
- **Recursion**

  The first recursive call to `bibesCutter` always falls into a base case (`tmp` has exactly 1 element). I suppose it is much cleaner to deal with it inline. At least you'd spare creating and destroying a vector.

  Once this is done' you'd notice that a code becomes tail recursive, so the recursion could be eliminated at all.
- **Correctness**

  It would be nice to prove that the algorithm yields the optimal solution. The request to fulfill with the remaining piece of pipe (`toCheck`) is selected pretty much at random. That, along with the above observation on recursion elimination, is a red flag.
- **Misc**

  `tmp` and `toCheck` are not best identifiers.

  `stoclLen` is a very funny typo.